# Can't Forward my port no matter what I do

Tags: networking, ssh, portforwarding

before I start this post I'd like to state that I'm somewhat familiar with the concept of networks and how they work but certain things still manage to confuse me so please excuse any dumb mistakes that I make but please understand that you can use as much "Networking Jargon" as you'd like.

So anyways, I recently converted my old PC into a small Linux server running Ubuntu (I know, I know *INSERT DISTRO HERE* is better but I'm learning as I go and I don't really feel like re-installing it).

Everything works perfectly well inside of my local network, but I would really love it if I had the ability access my server (SSH ,specifically) from outside of my network (I travel a lot). So I do the usual things:

- I set my server IP type to STATIC (192.168.0.101)
- I allowed firewall traffic (TCP/UDP) from port 22
- I added a "Virtual Server" that routes to 192.168.0.101 (my server's LAN IP) through port 22 (Port Forwarding [I'm using a TP-LINK WR841N v9 that's just how they called it])

And this is the part that's confusing me...

From what I understand, I needed to create a DYNAMIC DNS address In order for the IP to "stay static" so that I could connect to it (Like connecting to google.com instead of 10.something.something)

So I created a "NO-IP" account and managed to get the dynamic DNS to work. (I tested it by pinging the address)

But whenever I test my port from an external network it remains closed, I've exhausted all of my options so I'm turning to you Reddit, Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly... But in order to reach your local PC you'll need to have a **public static**  IP, so you'll be able to reach this PC from the Internet.

I don't know all the details, but I can suppose you'll have to get a static public IP (from your ISP) and then make port forwarding on the router to reach that server.
And then, having these things done you'll be able to configure DNS to reach that server.

I'd first recommend making everything work without DNS. That's the most challenging part. And then just configure DSN (it's going to be easy I guess...)